# How to include sharppcap library into Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharppcap

Sorry for the noob question. I don't really know how to make sharppcap library working in my project. I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your Project in Visual Studio-->Select `Add reference` --> Browse --> find the Sharppcap library and click done.

You should now be able to use the Sharpcap library in your project.

Answer (score 1):

In your application find **Reference** option, right click on it and select **Add Reference**. Choose your `sharppacp.dll` and add it.

At last write using sharppacp ; in your application.